# Xcode: use a static library in a framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, static-libraries

I have a framework that links against two static libraries. Each static library is a target and the framework is a target. The framework wraps the static libraries and clients of the framework only care about calling framework code (which in turn may call code from each static library).  Is is possible to have the framework include the required headers and object files? When I build I get the infamous `Include of non-module header inside framework module` error. Each static library exports its headers and I've added the headers as public headers in the framework. Still no luck (and I would think there's a solution that doesn't require this).

Comment: has you added the module map ?

Comment: @azimov is there an explanation of what that is? I've seen it referenced but never seen people say it's required.

Comment: it's an alternative for bridging header which can't be used inside of a framework, more details http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-maps . In my case I've created a framework which bundled several C libraries which are used in a swift project.

Comment: @azimov I've been reading that link. So the idea is I would have a custom `modulemap` for my framework that declares a module for each static library and points to the headers? Also, I'm not concerned about `swift`.

Comment: http://blog.bjhomer.com/2015/05/defining-modules-for-custom-libraries.html is helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each static library must export a `module.modulemap` file with its headers. Contrary to popular wisdom, once this is complete, you need ***not*** add a bunch of headers to the **Public** section of the framework's **Headers** *build phase* in order to alleviate the error. The process is described in detail here: https://bjhomer.com/2015/05/03/defining-modules-for-static-libraries/

Comment: Do you mean https://bjhomer.com/2015/05/03/defining-modules-for-static-libraries/ ?

Comment: Web framework must have changed out under us. Yes that's the new correct link. I edited the post. Thanks!